# automator applescript if then action

Tags: if-statement, applescript, automator

In Automator, can you do a `Run Applescript` like this:

```
if
```

then an action, then a `Run Applescript` like this:

```
end if
```

Is this possible? Here is an example:

[image: Example]

Yes I know you **can** get it to quit an application in Applescript and I don't need to do this with an action, but this is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - each **Run AppleScript** action (any action, actually) is a separate instance, so you will need to do your thing in the same script.  Automator is scriptable, so you might be able to do something like enable/disable an action (I haven't tried it, but the enabled property of an action appears to be settable).